# How do I automatically add the same Header element into existing xml files? For many xml files to do

Tags: xml

I have the same `<soapenv:Header>` element I need to add to the top of 300 xml files.  How would I do this automatically?

```
   <soapenv:Header>
  <v1:metadata>
     <v1:messageId>M1</v1:messageId>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v1:referenceMessageId>R1</v1:referenceMessageId>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v1:messagePriority>1</v1:messagePriority>
     <v1:containsSensitiveData>true</v1:containsSensitiveData>
     <v1:requestCount>1</v1:requestCount>
     <v1:requestType>INITIATE_LOAN_REVIEW</v1:requestType>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v1:properties>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <v1:property Id="A1" name="propertyA">a</v1:property>
     </v1:properties>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v1:businessEvent>a</v1:businessEvent>
  </v1:metadata>
```

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific.  Are you trying to append text before the XML conent?  Are you trying to add an XML node somewhere, or update an XML node?  Are these files in a RDBMS or on the file system?  What environment are you trying to do this with (PowerShell? Java?  Bash/Perl/Sed?)

Comment: I need to add soapenv:Header element to the top of each xml file.  I updated the description of question.  Thanks.

Comment: Question is improved a bit here but still need to know what environment/platform/language(s) you're working with -  a sample of what you've tried would be a good step in the right direction.

Comment: These are soap messages that have no soap header information.  All I need is to append that same block of text at the top of every xml file.

Comment: Yes, but a PowerShell solution isn't going to help you much if you're running this on Linux, and a Linux based solution isn't going to help you much if it turns out these files are actually stored in a table in SQL Server, and none of that is going to help if it turns out you actually have to modify these messages as part of an integration/SOA/ESB solution....

Comment: It should be trivial, try to find a library that can edit text files in the programming  language of your choice and find the tutorial to insert a new line at the top of the file. Then just traverse the entire directory of your xml files. Python can be an easy place to start if you’re new to programming.

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to use Nifi MergeContent processor. Specify a header.xml and footer.xml.  MergeContent will merge header to the top and insert footer at bottom.